# Problems with the data to be generated

Tags: r, combinations, simulation, sample

The code below is used to generate data with certain specifications:
Generate values of X1 close to 3 and values of X2 X3 X4 X5 close to zero (see scenario_1) . If I run the procedure for the single case (without a cycle) then they present correct values on average:

```
p13 = 0.493;p43 = 0.325;p25 = 0.335;p35 = 0.574;p12 = 0.868 
    std_e2 = sqrt(1-p12^2) 
    std_e3 = sqrt(1-(p13^2+p43^2)) 
    std_e5 = sqrt(1-(p25^2+p35^2+2*p25*p35*(p13*p12)))
    set.seed(1234)
set.seed(123)

mean_shifts=c(3,0,0,0,0)
X1=rnorm(1000)+mean_shifts[1]
X4=rnorm(1000)+mean_shifts[4]
X2=X1*p12+std_e2*rnorm(1000)+mean_shifts[2]
X3=X1*p13+X4*p43+std_e3*rnorm(1000)+mean_shifts[3]
X5=X2*p25+X3*p35+std_e5*rnorm(1000)+mean_shifts[5]
dati_1=cbind(X1,X2,X3,X4,X5);summary(dati_1)
```

In the general case I vary too much from the specs, as all variables result in an average close to 3

```
    z1<-c(0,1)
    z2<-c(0,1)
    z3<-c(0,1)
    z4<-c(0,1)
    z5<-c(0,1)
    s<-expand.grid(z1,z2,z3,z4,z5); s
    s<-s[-1,];s
    shift<-3
    scenari<-s*shift;scenari
    scenario_1<-scenari[1];scenario_1
    genereting_fuction <- function(n){ 
  sample <- vector("list") 
  for (i in 1:nrow(scenario_1)){
    X1=rnorm(n)+scenario_1[i,1]
    X4=rnorm(n)+scenario_1[i,4]
    X2=X1*p12+std_e2*rnorm(n)+scenario_1[i,2]
    X3=X1*p13+X4*p43+std_e3*rnorm(n)+scenario_1[i,3]
    X5=X2*p25+X3*p35+std_e5*rnorm(n)+scenario_1[i,5]
    sample[[i]]=cbind(X1,X2,X3,X4,X5)
    colnames(sample[[i]])<-c("X1","X2","X3","X4","X5")
  }
  sample
} 

set.seed(123)
dati_fault<- lapply(rep(10, 10), function(x) genereting_fuction(x));dati_fault
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you exactly try to achieve, but to get values close to 3 can be done directly from `rnorm`. The "closeness" can be set with sd.

`rnorm(n = 10, mean = 3, sd = 0)` would give you `[1] 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3` as the standard deviation is set to 0.

`rnorm(n = 10, mean = 3, sd = 0.1)` would give you `[1] 2.9403 2.9175 3.0106 2.9783 3.0492 3.0606 3.0007 3.0731 3.1317 3.0617`

So the more you increase the value of sd the more your random numbers will deviate from 3.

To create 5 columns based on your `mean_shifts` vector can be done like this:

```
set.seed(123)

mean_shifts = c(3, 0, 0, 0, 0)

dt <- as.data.frame(sapply(mean_shifts, function(x) {
  rnorm(n = 100, mean = x, sd = 0.1)
}))

head(dt, 10)

#        V1        V2         V3         V4        V5
# 1  3.0253  0.078774 -0.0375603  0.1014943  0.143040
# 2  2.9971  0.076904 -0.0561876 -0.1992748  0.104663
# 3  2.9957  0.033220 -0.0343917 -0.0427279  0.043529
# 4  3.1369 -0.100838  0.0090497  0.0116637  0.071518
# 5  2.9774 -0.011945  0.1598509 -0.0893208  0.091717
# 6  3.1516 -0.028040 -0.0088565  0.0333903 -0.266092
# 7  2.8451  0.056299  0.1080799  0.0411430  0.111028
# 8  3.0585 -0.037244  0.0630754 -0.0033036 -0.048499
# 9  3.0124  0.097697 -0.0113640 -0.2465898  0.023062
# 10 3.0216 -0.037458 -0.1532902  0.2571458 -0.029516

summary(dt)

 #       V1             V2                 V3                 V4                 V5         
 # Min.   :2.77   Min.   :-0.13598   Min.   :-0.20522   Min.   :-0.26432   Min.   :-0.2661  
 # 1st Qu.:2.93   1st Qu.:-0.06747   1st Qu.:-0.04977   1st Qu.:-0.06456   1st Qu.:-0.0410  
 # Median :3.00   Median :-0.01810   Median : 0.00819   Median : 0.00152   Median : 0.0151  
 # Mean   :2.99   Mean   : 0.00151   Mean   : 0.01257   Mean   :-0.00700   Mean   : 0.0152  
 # 3rd Qu.:3.05   3rd Qu.: 0.05481   3rd Qu.: 0.08537   3rd Qu.: 0.05165   3rd Qu.: 0.0817  
 # Max.   :3.22   Max.   : 0.32410   Max.   : 0.22931   Max.   : 0.25715   Max.   : 0.2430
```

Comment: I have to stick to a correlation script between the variables, which is why I don't use this function. My problem is that I don't get the values of the variables close to the set values [3,0,0] when I generate many samples.